# Smallest range that includes at least one number from each of the k lists

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

You have `k` lists of sorted integers. Find the smallest range that includes at least one number from each of the `k` lists.

For example,

```
List 1: [4, 10, 13, 14] 

List 2: [0, 9, 15, 18] 

List 3: [5, 18, 22, 30]
```

The smallest range here would be `[14, 18]` as it contains `14` from `list 1`, `15` from `list 2`, and `18` from `list 3`.

MY approach is:

- Just use a **MinHeap** and insert the first elements from `K` lists
- Remove the the min element and add the next element from the corresponding list
- Simultaneously track the max and min value so that we can calculate the minimum range

But the only issue I am facing is: Suppose for one list there is no more elements left than should I finish there or should I continue?

Comment: You should stop when you take min element from Heap and corresponding list is empty.

Comment: How about this approach
1) Collect start and end points of each list.
2) Sort it according to their starting points
3) Traverse the sorted pairs 
        Cases for overlapping and non overlapping pairs are considered and smallest interval is found

Please correct me if this approach is wrong.

Comment: Oops sorry pls ignore, I did not see the question carefully, we have to take care of individual elements too.

Answer (score 6):

Very nice O(n log n) algorithm!

You can finish there because you will never find the better interval fulfilling the given condition "range that includes at least one number from each of the k lists".

Suppose you are leaving current minimum `m` (the last element from some list) and instead you are removing something (not minimum) from another list. In that case the range can only grow (because minimum of the range is determined by `m`). So there is no point in doing that and you can just stop your algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not your terminating condition. Look at this example:

```
1: [0]
2: [1]
```

The range is quite clearly `[0,1]`, but if you stopped as soon as you detected an empty list, you would return `[0,0]`.

So, you can only stop once you know you have seen values from all `k` lists *and* one of the lists has run out of items. If you are keeping track of the min- and max-values for each list separately, this should be pretty easy, seeing as you can just make sure there is some min- and max-value for each list.

Comment: But OP is initially creating a min heap of size k by taking first element from all the k lists. That will cover above mentioned case and right range will be returned.

Comment: I still don't believe that to be true, because regardless of what is *left* in the min-heap, the given condition will still return a `[0,0]` interval.